# Вернуть значение из вложенной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Допустим есть вот такая функция реализующая систему оценок :

```
def get_grade (s1, s2, s3):
    
    grade_sum = (s1 + s2 + s3) / 3

    if 90 <= grade_sum <= 100:
        return "A"

    elif 80 <= grade_sum <= 90:
        return "B"

    elif 70 <= grade_sum <= 80:
        return "C"

    elif 60 <= grade_sum <= 70:
        return "D"

    elif 0 <= grade_sum <= 60:
        return "F"

    else:
        return None
```

И вот тесты к коду :

```
print ("Grade book")

def fixed_tests():


    print ('should return an A')

    def a_test_case():
        print (get_grade (95, 90, 93), "A", "get_grade(95, 90, 93)")
        print (get_grade (100, 85, 96), "A", "get_grade(100, 85, 96)")
        print (get_grade (92, 93, 94), "A", "get_grade(92, 93, 94)")
        print (get_grade (100, 100, 100), "A", "get_grade(100, 100, 100)")

    print ("should return a B")

    def b_test_case():
        print (get_grade (70, 70, 100), "B", "get_grade(70, 70, 100)")
        print (get_grade (82, 85, 87), "B", "get_grade(82, 85, 87)")
        print (get_grade (84, 79, 85), "B", "get_grade(84, 79, 85)")

    print ("should return a C")

    def c_test_case():
        print (get_grade (70, 70, 70), "C", "get_grade(70, 70, 70)")
        print (get_grade (75, 70, 79), "C", "get_grade(75, 70, 79)")
        print (get_grade (60, 82, 76), "C", "get_grade(60, 82, 76)")

    print ("should return a D")

    def d_test_case():
        print (get_grade (65, 70, 59), "D", "get_grade(65, 70, 59)")
        print (get_grade (66, 62, 68), "D", "get_grade(66, 62, 68)")
        print (get_grade (58, 62, 70), "D", "get_grade(58, 62, 70)")

    print ("should return an F")
    
    def f_test_case():
        print (get_grade (44, 55, 52), "F", "get_grade(44, 55, 52)")
        print (get_grade (48, 55, 52), "F", "get_grade(48, 55, 52)")
        print (get_grade (58, 59, 60), "F", "get_grade(58, 59, 60)")
        print (get_grade (0, 0, 0), "F", "get_grade(0, 0, 0)")


fixed_tests ()
```

Не могу понять, почему из вложенных функций в тестах не выводятся значения ?

[image: Скрин консоли]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас объявлены вложенные функции но они нигде не вызваны следовательно в процессе работы скрипта они не выполняются.

```py
def fixed_tests():


    print ('should return an A')

    def a_test_case():
        print (get_grade (95, 90, 93), "A", "get_grade(95, 90, 93)")
        print (get_grade (100, 85, 96), "A", "get_grade(100, 85, 96)")
        print (get_grade (92, 93, 94), "A", "get_grade(92, 93, 94)")
        print (get_grade (100, 100, 100), "A", "get_grade(100, 100, 100)")

    a_test_case() # Теперь функция вызвана
```

Comment: Спасибо,  я понял. Раньше почему-то думал, что если я вызываю саму функцию теста, то и вложенные в нее функции вызываются тоже вместе с ней.